# FIREBASE WARNING: Cannot read property 'myID' of undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've built an Angular app which uses Firebase Database. The app runs fine when using the `ng serve` command, however, after building the app and publishing to production it no longer renders and the **exception** `Cannot read property 'myID' of undefined` is shown in the console. I would like to know if this is a programming issue! or a bug in firebase.

** Edit -- Added console log and typescript/html code

** Error on chrome console **

```
[2018-05-09T12:40:48.707Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'myID' of undefined
    at https://somesiteonazure/main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1:1723933
    at t.newRequest_ (https://somesiteonazure/main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1:1723980)
    at t.startLongPoll (https://somesiteonazure/main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1:1723701)
    at t.start (https://somesiteonazure/main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1:1719991)
    at t.onHandshake_ (https://somesiteonazure/main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1:1734602)
    at t.onControl_ (https://somesiteonazure/main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1:1733956)
    at t.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (https://somesiteonazure/main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1:1733507)
    at t.onMessage_ (https://somesiteonazure/main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1:1731758)
    at https://somesiteonazure/main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1:1717476
    at K (https://somesiteonazure/main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1:1619201) 
a @ main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1
t.warn @ main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1
I @ main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.dbaf5fa354a8d018d4e5.bundle.js:1
n.runTask @ polyfills.dbaf5fa354a8d018d4e5.bundle.js:1
n.invokeTask @ polyfills.dbaf5fa354a8d018d4e5.bundle.js:1
invoke @ polyfills.dbaf5fa354a8d018d4e5.bundle.js:1
e.args.(anonymous function) @ polyfills.dbaf5fa354a8d018d4e5.bundle.js:1
setTimeout (async)
u @ polyfills.dbaf5fa354a8d018d4e5.bundle.js:1
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.dbaf5fa354a8d018d4e5.bundle.js:1
n.scheduleTask @ polyfills.dbaf5fa354a8d018d4e5.bundle.js:1
n.scheduleMacroTask @ polyfills.dbaf5fa354a8d018d4e5.bundle.js:1
v @ polyfills.dbaf5fa354a8d018d4e5.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.dbaf5fa354a8d018d4e5.bundle.js:1
F.i.(anonymous function) @ polyfills.dbaf5fa354a8d018d4e5.bundle.js:1
K @ main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1
e @ main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1
r @ main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1
t.handleResponse @ main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1
pRTLPCB @ .lp?start=t&ser=97147125&cb=1&v=5&ns=speed-test-29d7f:6
(anonymous) @ .lp?start=t&ser=97147125&cb=1&v=5&ns=speed-test-29d7f:9
polyfills.dbaf5fa354a8d018d4e5.bundle.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myID' of undefined
    at main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1
    at t.newRequest_ (main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1)
    at t.startLongPoll (main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1)
    at t.start (main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1)
    at t.onHandshake_ (main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1)
    at t.onControl_ (main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1)
    at t.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1)
    at t.onMessage_ (main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1)
    at main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1
    at K (main.66c1874d7f8af223e4e8.bundle.js:1)
```

**Typescript code**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Toastr } from '../../services/index';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { PapaParseService } from 'ngx-papaparse';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { PageLoadComponent } from '../pageload.component';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class DashboardComponent extends PageLoadComponent implements OnInit {
  listOfUsers = [];

  usersObservable: Observable<any[]>;
  selectedUserPingObservable: Observable<any[]>;
  selectedUserBandwidthObservable: Observable<any[]>;

  showUserInfo: boolean = false;
  pingView: boolean = true;

  numOfOnline: number = 0;
  numOfOffline: number = 0;

  selectedUser;

  constructor(
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
      super();

      this.db.list('/users').snapshotChanges().subscribe(listOfUsers => {
        this.listOfUsers = [];

        this.numOfOnline = 0;
        this.numOfOffline = 0;

        listOfUsers.forEach(item => {
          if(item){
            this.listOfUsers.push(item.payload.val())
            if(item.payload.val().status){
              this.numOfOnline++;
            }else{
              this.numOfOffline++;
            }
          }
        });
      });
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.toast = new Toastr(this.toastr);
    this.selectedUser = '';
  }

  viewUser(accountNt){
    this.selectedUser = accountNt;
    this.showUserInfo = true;
    this.getListOfPingsForUser(accountNt);
    this.getListOfBandwidthsForUser(accountNt);
  }

  getPingAvg(user){
    //todo
  }

  getBandwidthAvg(user){
    //todo
  }

  showPing(){
    this.pingView = true;
  }

  showBandwidth(){
    this.pingView = false;
  }

  closeUser(){
    this.showUserInfo = false;
    this.selectedUser = '';
  }

  getListOfPingsForUser(accountNt){
    this.selectedUserPingObservable = this.db.list('/users/' + accountNt + '/pings').valueChanges();
  }

  getListOfBandwidthsForUser(accountNt){
    this.selectedUserBandwidthObservable = this.db.list('/users/' + accountNt + '/bandwidths').valueChanges();
  }

  startPing(user){
    this.db.object('users/' + user.accountNt + '/commands').set({action: 1});
    this.toast.showSuccess("Ping requested!");
  }

  stopPing(user){
    this.db.object('users/' + user.accountNt + '/commands').set({action: 2});
    this.toast.showSuccess("Ping stopped!");
  }

  startBandwidthTest(user){
    this.db.object('users/' + user.accountNt + '/commands').set({action: 3});
    this.toast.showSuccess("Bandwidth test requested!");
  }
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="animated fadeIn">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="h1 text-muted text-right mb-4">
          <i class="icon-user-follow"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="h4 mb-0">{{numOfOnline + " / " + listOfUsers.length}}</div>
        <small class="text-uppercase text-success font-weight-bold">Online Users</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="h1 text-muted text-right mb-4">
          <i class="icon-user-follow"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="h4 mb-0">{{numOfOffline + " / " + listOfUsers.length}}</div>
        <small class="text-uppercase text-danger font-weight-bold">Offline Users</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-accent-warning" *ngIf="!showUserInfo">
    <div class="card-header {{theme+2}}">
      <h6 class="font-Size-{{fontSize}}">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i>&nbsp;Command Center</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body {{theme+5}}">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="search" id="mySubmissionSearch" name="mySubmissionSearch" class="{{theme+2}} search form-control"
                placeholder="{{'placeholder.search' | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="searchMyText">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-label="Search Users"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-hover table-outline mb-0">
        <thead class="table-secondary {{theme+2}}">
          <tr>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Site</th>
            <th>Ping</th>
            <th>Bandwidth</th>
            <th style="width: 30%">Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let user of listOfUsers | filter : searchMyText">
            <td><span class="badge badge-{{user.status?'success':'danger'}}">{{user.status ? 'Online' : 'Offline'}}</span></td>
            <td>
              <div><a [routerLink]="" (click)="viewUser(user.accountNt)">{{user.firstName + " " + user.lastName}}</a></div>
              <div class="small">{{user.accountNt}}</div>
            </td>
            <td>{{user.site}}</td>
            <td>
              <div>#: {{user.numOfPing}}</div>
              <div class="small">Avg: 0</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div>#: {{user.numOfBandwidth}}</div>
              <div class="small">Avg: 0</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" [disabled]="!user.status" (click)="startPing(user)">Request ping</button>
              | <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" [disabled]="!user.status" (click)="stopPing(user)">Stop ping</button>
              | <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" [disabled]="!user.status" (click)="startBandwidthTest(user)">Bandwidth</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngIf="listOfUsers.length==0">
            <td colspan="6">No users found!</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card card-accent-danger" *ngIf="showUserInfo">
    <div class="card-header {{theme+2}}">
      <h6 class="font-Size-{{fontSize}}">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i>&nbsp;Information for {{selectedUser}}</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body {{theme+5}}">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link {{pingView? 'show active' : ''}}" (click)="showPing()" data-toggle="tab">Ping</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link {{!pingView? 'show active' : ''}}" (click)="showBandwidth()" data-toggle="tab">Bandwidth</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-hover table-outline mb-0" *ngIf="pingView">
        <thead class="table-secondary {{theme+2}}">
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 50%">Timestamp</th>
            <th style="width: 50%">Ping</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let ping of (selectedUserPingObservable | async)">
            <td>{{ping.timestamp | date: short}}</td>
            <td>{{ping.ping | number:'1.0-0'}} ms</td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngIf="(selectedUserPingObservable | async)?.length==0">
            <td colspan="2">No data</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-hover table-outline mb-0" *ngIf="!pingView">
        <thead class="table-secondary {{theme+2}}">
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 50%">Timestamp</th>
            <th style="width: 50%">Bandwidth</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let bandwidth of (selectedUserBandwidthObservable | async)">
            <td>{{bandwidth.timestamp | date: short}}</td>
            <td>{{bandwidth.download | number:'1.0-0'}} Mbps</td>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngIf="(selectedUserBandwidthObservable | async)?.length==0">
            <td colspan="2">No data</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button (click)="closeUser()" class="btn btn-primary">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: This is a programming issue. But without knowing more we can't help you.

Comment: I don't see where you're calling for `myId` in your code.

Comment: That is the problem! i don't use it in my code! The `myID` is internal to firebase

Comment: I still wait for the answer on github. I suggest you to take a look at this post.. may be we will get the answer soon : https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/970#issuecomment-389434352

Comment: Having the same issue. The deployed app which worked for months has eventually crashed with this error in console. Defenently firebase bug.

Comment: Did you contact firebase support for this issue?

Comment: I didn't personally but others have on angularfire github https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/970#issuecomment-389434352

Comment: I asked if you contacted [firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/), not if you (or someone else) posted an issue on github.

Comment: @AndréKool I believe I've already answered you, not sure how your comment is useful

Comment: Nowhere in the github issue you linked is it stated that anyone contacted firebase support. Maybe I didn't make myself clear enough: Posting, or commenting on, an issue on github is **NOT** contacting firebase support. So last time: Did you contact firebase support? (you can find a link in my previous comment)

Comment: did you add firebase configuration to environment.prod.ts file?

Comment: @coder yes it was added for both dev and prod

Comment: can you post your authentication code

Comment: @Sajeetharan, I'm not using authentication for this project!

Comment: @AliAl-Munayer should I reward the bounty?

Comment: @AndreaM16 Yes please do! the workaround below works great!

Comment: @AliAl-Munayer oh okay, you should consider accepting the answer then

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by adding this to my app.component.ts file

`constructor() {
    localStorage.removeItem('firebase:previous_websocket_failure');
}`

I got the fix from this thread: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/970

Comment: Simple google search would take you to this solution but its just a temporary fix

Comment: On a simple network change this will not work again

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to update your code base, you can also delete the item direct from local storage in the browser.

Delete the item, then refresh the page and it should work.

Again, this is only a temp work around, it doesn't fix the problem.

[image: Delete local storage item]