# @firebase/database: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'myID' of undefined

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

Once I build my app to production into Firebase hosting, I get this error with some users :

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user
>   callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'myID' of undefined

screenshot

[image]

There is no variable "myID", **at any place**, into my code. Everything works fine into development but once it's built and in production the error appear to some user.

Here is my packages.json version:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.29",
"@angular-devkit/schematics": "^0.6.0",
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.10",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
"@schematics/package-update": "^0.6.0",
"ajv": "^6.0.0",
"angular2-recaptcha": "^0.6.0",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.7",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.5",
"firebase": "^4.13.1",
"firebase-admin": "^5.10.0",
"firebase-functions": "^0.8.2",
"ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
"rxjs": "^5.5.10",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
 },
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.10",
"@angular/language-service": "^5.2.10",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "^6.0.106",
"codelyzer": "^4.3.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~3.2.0",
"tslint": "~5.7.0",
"typescript": "~2.4.2"
}
```

**edit**
This issue only happen when I run my app after I deploy it to firebase using :

```
ng build --prod
firebase deploy
```

when I click on exception thrown at 1:789549 : [image]

I can see this code into the source console from my chrome browser:

```
(function(){var t={};return 
 t.id=this.myID,t.pw=this.myPW,t.ser=this.currentSerial,t}())
```

Here is my auth.service.ts. **The exception is thrown when I call the function Login()** only in production.

```
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { AppUser } from '../models/app-user';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
user$: Observable<firebase.User>;

constructor(
   private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
   private route: ActivatedRoute,
   private userService: UserService) {
   this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
 }

login(){
let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl') || '/';
localStorage.setItem('returnUrl', returnUrl);

this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
}

logout(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
}

get appUser$(): Observable<AppUser>{
  return this.user$
  .switchMap(user => {
    if (user) return this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges();
    return Observable.of(null);
});
}
}
```

Comment: Can you trace the line of code that is causing the warning and post it? I suspect it's somewhere where you're calling `document.write()`.

Comment: On a side note(for future reference): This issue has also been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244563/firebase-warning-cannot-read-property-myid-of-undefined) and [here](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/970)

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes when the exception is thrown, it's with my compile code in production. So, it doesn't break at a precise line. But, in my chrome browser I can see that the compile code is using "myID" but there is no variable "myID" at any place in my code. So, there is a package (probably @firebase/database or angularfire2 ?) somewhere that build all the firebase call with a variable "myID".

Comment: Yes, Firebase is the one making the call for `myID`. You should check when is the Exception thrown. Is it during a button click? Is it when the page loads? Is it when a certain change occurs on the database? I've noticed from similar posts, that this error generally occurs when you're using promises on your code. You might want to have a look at the promises you're returning.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes I edited my question by adding my Auth.service.ts. The exception happen in production after I clicked the login button. So on click, I call the login() function. Maybe you will be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

**Here is a workaround:**

If I modify my login() method by using:

`this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());`

instead of :

```
 this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
```

I am now able to connect into production. The root of this problem seems to be into the redirection function.

Comment: Sorry but I am already using popup so this isn't a workaround for me.

Comment: Damn, I will test my app further. I tried 10 accounts in 2 computer. Before I changed to popup it failed for the half.. after, it worked with all the accounts. I keep you inform if it happens again.

Comment: it seems that if you delete Firebase's cookies it will work, however once those are available it just starts spitting the error.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this in your app.component.ts

```
constructor() {
    localStorage.removeItem('firebase:previous_websocket_failure');
}
```

Comment: This is a temporary solution, on network fluctuation it will throw same error